# What is a variadic function?

Tags: function, eslint

Just saw mention of a variadic function in the [eslint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-spread). What is one?

Answer (score 0):

Variadic functions are functions which take a variable number of arguments.
for example printf in c or you can define your own such function in many languages. In java `...` are used to define variable arguments for a function. Similarly in c also same thing is used.

```
void simple_printf(const char* fmt...){
va_list args;
va_start(args, fmt);

while (*fmt != '\0') {
    if (*fmt == 'd') {
        int i = va_arg(args, int);
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    } else if (*fmt == 'c') {
        // note automatic conversion to integral type
        int c = va_arg(args, int);
        std::cout << static_cast<char>(c) << '\n';
    } else if (*fmt == 'f') {
        double d = va_arg(args, double);
        std::cout << d << '\n';
    }
    ++fmt;
}

va_end(args);
```

}

this is a variadic function in c.

In the link you asked it is said that for calling such functions in ESLint before new update one must use .apply() but from new update you can simply ignore it and just add `...`before parameter you are passing as given the link.

before:

`var args = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Math.max.apply(Math, args);`

now:

`var args = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Math.max(...args);`

now u dont need to use .apply()